# If $X$ is a metric space and $E \subset X$, then $\overline{E}$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I would like to understand how a certain statement below follows from the previous statements.

> Theorem If $X$ is a metric space and $E \subset X$, then $\overline{E}$ is closed.

> Proof. If $p \in X$ and $p \notin \overline{E}$ then $p$ is neither a point of $E$ nor a limit point of $E$. Hence $p$ has a neighborhood which does not intersect $E$. The complement of $\overline{E}$ is therefore open. Hence $\overline{E}$ is closed.

Since $p$ has a neighborhood which does not intersect $E$. I was wondering how it follows from "$p$ has a neighborhood which does not intersect $E$ " that the complement of $\overline{E}$ is open if and only if $(\overline{E})^{c}$ is open? At first I thought that since $p$ has a neighborhood, $N_{r}(p)$, which intersects $E^{c}$, then $N_{r}(p) \subset E^{c} \subset \overline{E^{c}}$ since $\overline{E^{c}} = E^{c} \cup (E^{c}$)'. But, I don't think that $\overline{E^{c}}$ necessarily equals $(\overline{E})^{c}$.

Comment: What does $\overline{E}^c$ mean to you?

Comment: the complement of $\overline{E}$.

Comment: "$\overline{E}$ is closed" is a tautology. It is closed *by definition*. Similarly "the complement of $\overline{E}$ is open if and only if $(\overline{E})^{c}$ is open" doesn't follow from anything because they are both literally the same statement and are therefore trivially equivalent. By the way, $(\overline{E})^{c}$ is open because $\overline{E}$ is closed.

Comment: Well then I'm not sure what your question is. At first I thought you were asking how the statement "then $p$ has a neighborhood which does not intersect $E$" follows from the previous remarks on the proof, but you seem to have just asked why is the complement of $\overline{E}$ open if and only if the complement of $\overline{E}$ is open, and that's obvious.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by $\overline{E}$ is a tautology? That is what we're trying to prove. The entire point of putting the equivalence there is to make it more explicit.

Comment: I explained what I meant by tautology. $\overline{E}$ is closed because it is the closure of $E$, which is closed by definition.

Comment: I think you need to give the definition you are using for $\overline{E}$.

Comment: @SeraPhim: That $\operatorname{cl}E$ is closed is not a tautology. Whether one defines it as the set of points $p$ such that every open nbhd of $p$ meets $E$ or as the intersection of all closed sets containing $E$, one still has to prove that it is a closed set. The proofs are trivial, but they are needed.

Comment: I think that many of the above posters need to reread what I wrote, and then perhaps comment.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes I suppose you're right. I guess I'm thinking of the closure as being the smallest closed set containing $E$, in which case it being closed would be trivial.

Comment: In that case you need to prove such a set exists.

Comment: @JustinYoung: prove that what set exists?

Comment: Here is the point of confusion: you wrote ". . . that the complement of $\overline{E}$ is open if and only if $(\overline{E})^c$ is open?" The phrase "complement of $\overline{E}$" **is written to mean** "$(\overline{E})^c$". But I think you interpreted it as "$\overline{E^c}$, which is not the case.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is literally $(\overline{E})^{c}$. My question was basically how do we get that the complement of $\overline{E}$ is open as a consequence of $p$ having a neighborhood which does not intersect $E$?

Comment: The smallest closed set containing E, sorry I was responding to @SeraPhim

Comment: @Brian M. Scott "Whether one defines it as the set of points p such that every open nbhd of p meets E or as the intersection of all closed sets containing E, one still has to prove that it is a closed set."

If you use the second definition, "$\bar{E} :=$ the intersection of all closed sets containing $E$," then closure is automatic. If you're at the point of discussing closures of sets, you've already established that finite unions and arbitrary intersections of closed sets are closed. It shouldn't be a fact you need to prove separately.

Comment: @RiversMcForge: No, closure is not automatic: you have to have proved already that the arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed. The fact that this is trivial and the fact that at this point you almost certainly **have** proved it do not turn it into a tautology. Note that I am not arguing that it necessarily has to be explicitly noted, though early in a course an instructor might in fact want that. My point is that it is not a **tautology**, and indeed it is not: an actual argument underlies it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I didn't necessarily say it was a tautology (although, in a sense, every true mathematical statement **is** a tautology). I said it was *automatic,* which I think is not meaningfully different in spirit to your acknowledgement that it is "trivial".

Comment: @RiversMcForge: **You** didn’t say that it was a tautology, but **SeraPhim** did, and my comment was in response to that. Thus, your comment to me was largely a *non sequitur*, since in it you are objecting to an assertion that I did not in fact make and ignoring the one that I **did** make. I naturally assumed that you were talking about the latter and using *automatic* as a paraphrase of *tautological*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Saying "$\bar{E}$ is closed" could indeed be a tautology, depending on how $\bar{E}$ has been defined in the course (e.g. "the smallest closed set containing $E$"). But I agree that strictly speaking, "the intersection of all closed sets containing $E$" is not a *tautological* description/definition of the closure of $E$, although showing that they are equivalent is *trivial*.

Comment: You are right that $\overline {E^c}$ does not necessarily equal $(\overline E)^c.$ For example, in $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|,$ if $E=[0,\infty)$ then  $\overline {E^c}=(-\infty,0]$ and $(\overline E)^c=(-\infty,0).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument goes like this. If $p$ is not in $\operatorname{cl}E$, then by definition $p\notin E$ and $p$ is not a limit point of $E$. This implies that $p$ has a nbhd $N_p$ that does not intersect $E$. We can do this for each $p\in X\setminus\operatorname{cl}E$, so

$$X\setminus\operatorname{cl}E\subseteq\bigcup_{p\in X\setminus\operatorname{cl}E}N_p\subseteq X\setminus\operatorname{cl}E\;.$$

But then

$$X\setminus\operatorname{cl}E=\bigcup_{p\in X\setminus\operatorname{cl}E}N_p\;,$$

which, being a union of open sets, is open. By definition the complement of $X\setminus\operatorname{cl}E$ is then closed, and

$$X\setminus(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}E)=\operatorname{cl}E\;,$$

so $\operatorname{cl}E$ is closed.

Comment: what do you mean by a neighborhood that does not intersect E?

Comment: @DivyanshVerma: $N_p$ is a nbhd of $p$, meaning that there is an open set $U$ such that $p\in U\subseteq N_p$, and $N_p\cap E=\varnothing$ ($N_p$ ‘does not intersect $E$’).